# reducer is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am fairly new to `react-redux` and I am getting this wierd error. It says that my `rootReducer` is not defined. `rootReducer` is the constant that I create after I combine my reducers. This is my code:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import taskReducer from './handle-action';

rootReducer = combineReducers({
    tasks: taskReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `const rootReducer  = combineReducers({
    tasks: taskReducer
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you export must be a variable or function so it should be `const or var or let`

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import taskReducer from './handle-action';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    tasks: taskReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed to define a `rootReducer` variable

`const rootReducer = combineReducers({ tasks: taskReducer });`

or

`export default combineReducers({ tasks: taskReducer });`

Comment: Thanks, that solved this problem, but now when I export the constant, it says that it does not contain an export named 'rootReducer'. Do I need to change my export too?

Comment: How do you `import`ing it? you just need to use `import rootReducer from './myreducer'`

Comment: Yeah thanks again now it works, I just needed to remove the brackets. I don't know why I put them there.